# amdgpu dkms fails for running kernel

Tags: linux, centos, amd-graphics-card

After updating my Centos 8 workstation, I got a black screen after booting to Centos, I suspected some problem with the graphics card, since I could ssh to my machine and everything else would work fine.

I installed the latest drivers from amd following the [steps recommended by AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux) to install the drivers. I've also checked that my card is in the "Product Family Compatibility"section.

I get a warning when installing, which makes me think if the latest drivers are not compatible with the kernel I'm running:

```
WARNING: amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel
```

Is there anything I can do, except running the version before my update?

## System Info

- Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2145 CPU @ 3.70GHz
- VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lexa XT [Radeon PRO WX 3100]
- "CentOS Linux release 8.1.1911 (Core) "
- Linux 4.18.0-147.3.1.el8_1.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 23:55:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- status of the amdgpu or radeon kernel module:

  ```
  amdgpu, 19.30-909144.el8: added
  ```
- status of modules, that contain "kms" or "drm", in the Linux kernel:

  ```
  amdgpu               3600384  0
  chash                  16384  1 amdgpu
  amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdgpu
  gpu_sched              32768  1 amdgpu
  drm_kms_helper        217088  1 amdgpu
  ttm                   110592  1 amdgpu
  drm                   524288  4 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,ttm
  i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 igb,amdgpu
  ```
- UEFI boot is not disabled

Comment: Are you using UEFI boot or did you disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my Problem by

1. uninstalling amdgpu driver by following amd recommendation on [how to uninstall amd drivers](https://www.amd.com/de/support/kb/faq/gpu-637): running `sudo amdgpu-uninstall` in terminal emulator.
2. Updating to kernel version `4.18.0-147.5.1.el18_1.x86_64`
3. Installing `amdgpu-pro-versionlist-19.50-1011208.el8.x86_64`
4. Rebooting